# ValueError: Input 0 of layer dense is incompatible

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

Im learning neural networks with a super simple binary Network. All this Network has to do is "learn" that the prediction depends on the first column only of the dataset provided [Data and Target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPsdw.png). It compiled ok but when trying to test the network i get the error message

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer dense_38 is incompatible with the layer: 
expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 3 but received input with shape 
[None, 1]
```

I dont understand which layer dense-38 its talking about, shouldnt it be only 18 neurons in the first layern, then 2, then 1 ? This is my code.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x_train = np.array([[[0, 1, 0]], [[0, 1, 1]], [[0, 0, 0]], [[1, 0, 0]], [[1, 1, 1]], [[1, 0, 1]]])
y_train = np.array([[[0]], [[0]], [[0]], [[1]], [[1]], [[1]]])

x_test = np.array([[[0, 0, 0]], [[1, 0, 0]], [[1, 1, 1]]])
y_test = np.array([[[0]], [[1]], [[1]]])

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=tf.nn.softmax))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['binary_accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=3)

print('\n')
val_loss, val_acc = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)

predictions = model.predict([0])
```

Comment: Welcome to SO; please post the **full** error trace (not here, edit & update your post), and remove any code that comes *after* the error - see how to create a [mre].

Comment: You can figure out which "dense" is which by adding an optional "name" to each layer in your network.   I think the error is because you haven't indicated to the model what kind of shape the inputs have.

Answer (score 0):

you are giving wrong input to predict .  replace

```
model.predict([0])
```

with

```
model.predict(x_test[0])
```

or

```
model.predict([[0,0,0]])
```

providing [gist](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/mohantym/340647177c46e42e031fc284e94384bc/stack_68779200.ipynb) for reference